# Having a hard time using the constructor to start a class c++

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, openframeworks

I'm having a hard time tcreating a class using the constructor. Not sure what's happening. Sometimes it loads, sometimes it doesn't; not sure what's going on.
This is my .h from that class:

```
ScreenBasics(int _answersFader, int _answersFaderVel, ofPoint _answersPos, size_t _numberOfanswers, string *_answersText, ofPoint _questionPos, string _questionText, bool _isHovered, bool _isClicked);
```

And this is my .cpp from that class:

```
ScreenBasics::ScreenBasics(int _answersFader, int _answersFaderVel, ofPoint _answersPos, size_t _numberOfAnswers, string *_answersText, ofPoint _questionPos, string _questionText, bool _isHovered, bool _isClicked, string _pathToFont):answersFader(_answersFader), answersFaderVel(_answersFaderVel), answersPos(_answersPos), numberOfAnswers(_numberOfAnswers),answersText(new string[numberOfAnswers]),questionPos(_questionPos), isHovered(_isHovered), isClicked(_isClicked){

answersText = _answersText;
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfAnswers; i++){
 //we create our text
 ofTrueTypeFont tmp;
 answers.push_back(tmp);
 answers[i].loadFont(_pathToFont, 24);
 // we create our boundary box
 ofRectangle box;
 answersBox.push_back(box);        
 }
}
```

And this is how I create it on my ofApp.cpp:

```
int answersFader3 = 0;
int answersFader3Vel = 2;
ofPoint answersPos3 = ofPoint(( width / 2 ) - ( width / 10 ),( height / 2 ) - ( height / 5 ));
size_t numberOfAnswers3 = 3;
string answersText3[] = {"1.Unisex", "2. Female", "3.Male"};
ofPoint questionPos3 = ofPoint(( width / 2 ) - ( width / 8), ( height / 2) - ( height / 3 ));
string questionText3 = "What Gender's perfume are you looking for?";
bool isHovered3 = false;
bool isClicked3 = false;
// screen3 was created as a pointer in the .h file ScreenBasics *screen3;
screen3 = new ScreenBasics(answersFader3, answersFader3Vel, answersPos3, numberOfAnswers3,     answersText3, questionPos3, questionText3, isHovered3, isClicked3, pathToFont);
```

Sometimes when I create the app it thrown me this error:
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc.

Any thoughts?

Comment: for a start, you initialize `answersText(new string[numberOfAnswers])` in the ctor initializer list, but then you do `answersText = _answersText` which immediately leaks the memory allocated via `new`. To avoid this sort of error, stop using pointers and `new`

Comment: Your code creates the new `ScreenBasics` object as holding a pointer to `answersText3[]`. If the latter is a local variable it will be destroyed when this function returns.

Comment: To get better help post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); if you just post fragments like this then we have to make a lot of guesses about what is going on in the code not shown.

Comment: @Matt McNabb That makes sense, cause when I get the error and I open the compiler log. answersText is supposed to have 3 values it only has 1. Is there any way to pass that string array to answersText using the constructor?

Comment: Take out the line `answersText = _answersText`. Instead, copy 3 pointers from `_answersText` into `answersText`. However this is a bad design, it would be better to make `answersText` be a vector of strings. And your function parameter list has to include a way for the function to know how many strings there are, instead of hardcoding `3`.

Comment: I tried passing a string pointer to the vector but it doesn't work. So the best thing I could do would be to pass a vector to a vector through the constructor?

Comment: you could, (a) pass a vector, (b) pass a pointer range, (c) pass a start pointer plus the length of the array

Comment: Also your constructor is fairly complicated to use; perhaps a better design would be to have all of those other parameters settable separately if required, rather than being constructor parameters